# how to know inform shell script that apple script / automator workflow has finished?

Tags: shell, applescript, zsh, automator, osascript

**Problem**:
I want to make a shell script that exports all contacts inside the macOS's address book to a specific folder (for backup purposes). To do that, I want to use a simple automator workflow or apple script. However, I need to know when that apple script / automator workflow has finished so that I can proceed my shell script. I want my shell script to wait for the apple script to export all cards.

**Question**
Is there a way inside an apple script or automator workflow to report back to a shell script that it has finished?

Pseudo shell script:

```
!/bin/zsh

do
  ## nothing
while [applescript does not return true]

## proceed shell script
```

(sorry for the maybe wrong shell script syntax).

Comment: Do you launch yourself the applescript ot is it automated by the computer?

Comment: I thought I would lunch it inside my shell script using osascript ...